# Compare columns in a dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dataframes (Di_1). Each dataframe has the same number of columns, column names, number of rows and row indexes. I also have a list of the names of the dataframes (dfs). I would like to compare the contents of one of the columns (A) in each dataframe with those of the last dataframe in the list to see whether they are the same. For example:

```
df_A = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,0,1,0]})
df_B = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,0,0]})

Di_1 = {'X': df_A, 'Y': df_B}

dfs  = ['X','Y']
```

I tried:

```
for df in dfs:
    Di_1[str(df)]['True'] = Di_1[str(df)]['A'] .equals(Di_1[str(dfs[-1])]['A'])
```

I got:

```
[0,0,0,0]
```

I would like to get:

```
[1,0,0,1]
```

My attempt is checking whether the whole column is the same but I would instead please like to get it to go through each dataframe row by row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you make things too complicated here. You can

```
series_last = Di_1[dfs[-1]]['A']

for df in map(Di_1.get, dfs):
    df['True'] = df['A'] == series_last
```

This will produce as result:

```
>>> df_A
   A   True
0  1   True
1  0  False
2  1  False
3  0   True
>>> df_B
   A  True
0  1  True
1  1  True
2  0  True
3  0  True
```

So each `df_i` has an extra column named `'True'` (perhaps you better use a different name), that checks if for a specific row, the value is the same as the one in the `series_last`.

In case the `dfs` contains something else than strings, we can first convert these to strings:

```
series_last = Di_1[str(dfs[-1])]['A']

for df in map(Di_1.get, map(str, dfs)):
    df['True'] = df['A'] == series_last
```

Comment: This is what I need because it also works when there are more than 2 dataframes, thank you.

Comment: On my real code I had to put "series_last = Di_1[str(dfs[-1])]['A']" because my dataframes are numbered. Where can I put the "str" in the for loop please?

Comment: @R.Cox: why do you need `str(..)` in the first place. The `dfs` list contains strings, so `str(..)` will be a no-op here.

Comment: it's because the real list doesn't contain strings; I got my example wrong.

Comment: It has dtype: int64

Comment: To get this to work on my real problem I used df.sort_index() on each dataframe in my dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Create a list:

```
l=[Di_1[i] for i in dfs]
```

Then using `isin()` you can compare the first and last df

```
l[0].isin(l[-1]).astype(int)
```

---

```
   A
0  1
1  0
2  0
3  1
```